# using CSS with a survey website (survey gizmo)

Tags: html, css, survey

So, I am a fairly inexperienced web programmer, and just use little bits of HTML or CSS here or there. I really know essentially nothing about any of this.

With my current problem, I can't quite decide if it's my lack of knowledge with web coding or if it's the way this survey tool is set up.

In survey gizmo, you can create 'custom CSS' coding in an external location to the survey itself. I think this acts as an external CSS stylesheet, but you can put multiple styles there.

Then, for each page of the survey, you can link to the styles you defined in that other places, or you can link to them for each question. I also could modify the head for the page, and there are options for 'custom HTML' also located in a separate document.

I tried talking to survey gizmo (SG) help about this, but their attitude is that I should understand it, or I should pay them to program it for me...

What I'm trying to do is make it so that I have a video player on the left-hand side of the screen, and then have a number of questions on the right-hand side of the screen, that can be scrolled through, while the video player stays still.

Now, the examples SG provides for CSS are things that look like this:

```
.width-33{ 
clear: none; 
float: left; 
width: 33%; }
```

I don't really understand what this is - is it a class, or somehow approximating a stylesheet name? In any case, I can apply this successfully to a survey question. But I don't know how to apply a more complicated structure successfully. To apply this, I click on my survey question and there is a field for custom CSS style, and I enter "width-33" in that field.

I'd like to do something like what appears here: http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/QMsuD/1/ but switched around (I don't need to know how to switch it around, just how to get it to work in SG at all).

The CSS from that page looks like this

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
html,
body,
.Container {
    height: 100%;
}
.Container:before {
    content: '';
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.Header {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    background-color: #6ea364;
}
.Content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.Content:after {
    content: '';
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
.Wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.Wrapper > div {
    height: 100%;
}
.LeftContent {
    background-color: purple;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.LeftContent:hover {
    overflow: auto;
}
.RightContent {
    background-color: orange;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

and the HTML looks like this:

```
 <div class="Container">
    <div class="Header">
        <p>The Header div height is not fixed (But he can be if you want it to)</p>
        <p>This Layout has been tested on: IE10, IE9, IE8, FireFox, Chrome, Safari, Opera. using Pure CSS 2.1 only</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Content">
        <div class="Wrapper">
            <div class="RightContent">
                <p>You can fix the width of this content.</p>
                <p>if you wont, his width will stretch just as it needs to.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="LeftContent">
                <p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p>
                <p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p>
                <p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p>
                <p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p>
                <p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p>
                <p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p>
                <p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p>
                <p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p><p>this will scroll</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So, I am just trying to figure out how to get this to work. I realize it's probably confusing trying to understand how a survey tool utilizes this, but I'm hoping that maybe there's something going on here that actually makes sense to experienced programmers.

Basically, how do I parse this code example to shoehorn it into the survey gizmo system? How do I turn that CSS code above into an external style sheet, and once I do that, will it work if I just tell the survey tool to use the CSS style "leftContent" (my video player) and CSS style "rightContent" (my questions).

Any other suggestions for how to make this work? The tool also allows for javascript.

Answer (score 0):

To address your first question. What this piece of code is.. let's break it down.

```
.width-33 { 
    // elements with a float are allowed next to the object with this class. It's redundant though because it has this property by default.
    clear: none;
    // align this object to the left of it's parent container. Multiple items with float:left will be placed next to each other.
    float: left;
    // the width is 33% of the parent containers' width. The classname is named after this property.
    width: 33%; 
}
```

You were correct thinking this is a class. When assigned to a div like this: `<div class="width-33"></div>`, this div will get those properties.

At this point, it's unclear to me how you can apply styling within Survey Gizmo. You say you can create some sort of external stylesheet and assign that stylesheet to different questions. And then that there also is a 'custom HTML' part.

From what you're trying to achieve, I think you'll need the custom HTML part. You'll want to address the container containing all the questions, not the questions themselves. So you need to figure out how all these different parts of the survey are named, what their classnames are or what their id is.
If this is not clear from the backend editor or dashboard you're creating the survey in, I suggest previewing the survey and clicking right click 'inspect' or 'inspect element'. The inspector tools will open and you'll be able to see the source code. You'll need to look for the name of the container containing the questions and the one containing the video.

If you have those you can go create your layout.
It's a very basic layout. I'll explain since you can propably do it in less lines than in your example.

The video-container and the questions-container need to be placed next to each other. Both containers should fill the entire height of the screen. Last, you'll want the user to be able to scroll inside the questions-container.

```
.video-container {
    height: 100vh; // vh stands for view height. See explanation below
    float: left;
    width: 40%; // or any other width.
}
.questions-container {
    height: 100vh;
    float: left; // with both elements floated to the left, they'll be placed next to each other.
    overflow: auto; // when the questions are longer than the container is high, a scrollbar will be added and you'll be able to scroll
    width: 60%; // 100% - 40% (the other element)
}
```

Why choose `100vh` and not `100%`? With `100%` you need to make sure any other parent container of that container also needs to have a height of 100%. All the way up to the `<body>` tag. That's done in the second code block in your example.

If the two containers don't position themselves next to each other, some margin or padding might be giving them extra width, because those are added on top. 40% + 10px + 50px for example.
The most simple solution would be to remove those by adding `padding: 0;` and `margin: 0;`.

If you do want to add padding I suggest adding the following styles:

```
.video-container {
    height: 100vh; 
    float: left;
    width: 40%;

    box-sizing: border-box; // any padding (and borders) will be inset and will not be added to the total width. This doesn't count for margin!
    padding: 20px; // or whatever width of padding you want
}
```

I hope this helps.